# Horizontally and vertically arrange <li> simultaneously

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation structure for my site that resembles the Office 2007-2013 ribbon that looks like this in markup.

This is the content of each "tab" (each of these are contained in another `<ul>` that represents each top-level tab and its content. Tab visibility is controlled by javascript).

```
<ul> <!-- this UL represents the tab content -->
    <li> <!-- this LI represents the "button group" -->
         <p>Paragraph</p>
         <ul>
             <li><a href="#"><span>Foo</span></a></li>
             <li><a href="#"><span>Bar</span></a></li>
             <li><a href="#"><span>Baz</span></a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <!-- this LI represents the "button group" -->
         <p>Styles</p>
         <ul>
             <li><a href="#"><span>Foo</span></a></li>
             <li><a href="#"><span>Bar</span></a></li>
             <li><a href="#"><span>Baz</span></a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The `<p>` in each button-group is absolutely positioned to the bottom-centre of each button-group, the `<ul>` has its own height defined.

Presently all of the innermost `<li><a>` elements are arranged horizontally in a single row (as big chunky buttons), or in a vertical arrangement with at most 3 `<li>` elements per `<ul>` as small text-only buttons.

Here is my jsFiddle of what I've got so far, showing only chunky buttons:

http://jsfiddle.net/ahG7K/2/

But I want a combination approach that looks like this:

[image: two boxes arranged horizontally, and two more arranged vertically]

But I'm stuck for a good way to implement this without modifying the HTML at all, and also avoiding absolute positioning (for fear of wrecking havoc with different font-sizes or other details, plus it just feels impure).

Comment: your jsfiddle doesn't really help to see or understand your question. sketch of 4 boxes and code with a bunch of 3 li . you're confusing everybody i believe.

Comment: Closest weird thing I could come up with o_o [here](http://jsbin.com/inahuw/1/)

Comment: How do you determine what should be styled as a 'chunky' button and what should be styled as 'text only'?

Comment: @BrianL in this case, there will always be 4 items, and I want the last 2 to be stacked vertically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways of going about this with pure CSS.  Neither method will work in IE<10.

The first is pretty simple, and has pretty good browser support (though Firefox is missing support for a few related properties like break-before and column-span):

http://cssdeck.com/labs/q7sc2mcc

```
ul {
  columns: 3;
}
```

Prefixes may be required:  http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn

The second method requires more CSS to pull off and you have to specify a height, but you'll have a lot more control over the result.  Support is limited to browsers that support wrapping from the Flexbox module (currently only Opera, Chrome, and IE10 do).

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/pldLa

```
ul {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
  -ms-flex-flow: column wrap;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 10em;
}

li {
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Float *can* be used for this purpose as well, but you have to know the widths in advance.  To force the last one to appear below the 2nd to last, use this formula:  `[width of parent] / [num of elements - 1]`

http://cssdeck.com/labs/aksfizam (for 4 elements)

```
li {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}
```

Comment: Ahhh, `columns` - I wouldn't have thought of that! Clever. I'll look into implementing this and probably resorting to a workaround for IE. I'll note that neither example works in Chrome 27 but they do work in IE11 on Windows 8.1 Preview, but when I add the `-webkit-` prefix it works fine.

Comment: Yes, Chrome still requires prefixes for the columns property.  I've added a fix for the Flexbox sample in Chrome (it *should* have worked with the original code).